# darktable can't startup

Tags: photo-management, photo, color-management

During darktable startup from console I get:

```
nnnn@nn:~$ darktable

darktable: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcolordprivate.so.1: undefined symbol: cmsGetHeaderCreator
```

I tried to reinstall: colord, libcolord1, darktable, but to no avail (the same error).
Some hours ago, I managed to successfully run darktable, but after a short time, darktable ended unexpectedly without any error message or crash report.
It is the first time that I have tried to use darktable since dist upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10.

Can anybody provide me with a useful solution?

(Google return only 2 sites with that error phrase.)

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge darktable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmjdebruijn/darktable-release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install darktable; sudo apt-get autoremove
```